# woocommerce internal server error on schedule job execution

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have create a custom plugin for products update in [woocommerce](/questions/tagged/woocommerce) from an other system. I have also add my plugin in cron schedule of [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress).

But when i have a lot of products to update, i get error 500, internal server error.

In the start the procedure interrupted with error about time limit, so i raise the time limit ( set_time_limit(xxxxx);

Furthermore i have raise memory limit in wp-config.php file
What else i can do ?

Regards
S

Comment: Maybe consider using the API to update the products from the other system.

Comment: i have functions for products, varations,images and orders. Can i do all thoses things with the api?

Comment: Probably. I would look at the [API docs](http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/) and the available code [libraries](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/#section-5)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to advice without seeing code. Consider to update only part of products in one execute - make few crons one after another to do all job.

Comment: I now that is hard without code. I am asking to see if there is something that i can do in general. SOme thing in wp that free memory or ...
If i have a few records i have no problem.